AWS CDK - How to get Cross-Account AND Cross-Region deployments to work (TypeScript)
I am attempting to setup CDK (v2) Stack using TypeScript to create a Pipeline Stack (Account A, region A) that contains Stages. One stage being CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction() for Account B, region B.

I have bootstrapped all accounts and regions
I am using Environment Stack Property (on all stacks)
I am using cdk.Pipeline() --> where the problem resides

Hard to find examples online for this setup. Has anyone attempted this before?
This github solution did not work for me:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11965

I am not sure the correct configuration for this. The blocker/issue relates to the Artifact Bucket(s) and KMS Key. Depending on setup, I've seen the following errors:

Error: Cannot add assets to a Stack that uses the BootstraplessSynthesizer
An error occurred while validating the artifact bucket 'ACCOUNT_B_BUCKET_NAME':The bucket named ACCOUNT_B_BUCKET_NAME is not located in the REGION_B AWS region. Choose a valid artifact bucket in 'REGION_B', or create a new artifact bucket to use in your pipeline.
Error: Artifact Bucket must have a KMS Key to add cross-account action 'ACTION_STAGE_NAME' (pipeline account: 'ACCOUNT_A', action account: 'ACCOUNT_B'). Create Pipeline with 'crossAccountKeys: true' (or pass an existing Bucket with a key)

I would expect the CDK Stack to be smart enough to create/allow the creation of cross-account and cross-region resources to deploy based on the properties of the CDK Constructs.
UPDATE 9/23/2024
MainStack.ts (runs in SOURCE Aws Account)
    ...
    const cp_stackName = `${service}-cp-stack`;
    const cp_props: PipelineStackProps = {
        // stackProps (inherited)
        crossRegionReferences: true,

        // SOURCE ACCOUNT WHERE PIPELINE IS CREATED/RUN
        env: {
          account: {SOUREC_ACCOUNT_A_ID},
          region: {SOURCE_ACCOUNT_A_REGION}
        },
        tags: props.tags,
        stackName: cp_stackName
    };
    new PipelineStack(this, cp_stackName, cp_props);

PipelineStack.ts (runs in SOURCE Aws Account but certain Pipeline Stages deploy in TARGET Aws Account)
   // create destination/target bucket before this point
   // destination bucket should have KMS Key defined
   const destinationBucketName = {GRAB_FROM_OUTSIDE_THIS_STACK};

   // Kms Key must be a string reference, not a Token ref
   const destinationEncryptionKey = Key.fromKeyArn(this, 'DestinationBucketKey', KEY_ARN);
   ...
    targetBucket = Bucket.fromBucketAttributes(this, 'DestBucket', {
        account: TARGET_ACCOUNT_B_ID,
        bucketName: destinationBucketName,
        region: TARGET_ACCOUNT_B_REGION,
        encryptionKey: destinationEncryptionKey // IMPORTANT: must include this prop
    });
    ... 

    // create cross-account, cross-region stage/action
    const crossAcctCrossRegionAction = new CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
            account: TARGET_ACCOUNT_B_ID,
            region: TARGET_ACCOUNT_B_REGION,

            // Excluding other settings for brevity
        });

    ...
    const cp = new Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
        ...
        // By default cross-account deployments are enabled
        // Create KMS keys for cross-account deployments.
        // This controls whether the pipeline is enabled for cross-account deployments
        // 
        // If you do not need cross-account deployments, you can set this to false to not 
        // create those keys and save on that cost (the artifact bucket will be encrypted with an AWS-managed key). 
        // However, cross-account deployments will no longer be possible.
        // crossAccountKeys: true,
        crossRegionReplicationBuckets: {
            'eu-west-1': targetBucket
        },
        reuseCrossRegionSupportStacks: true,

        // create IAM ROLE prior to this point
        // role should have proper perms to destination bucket
        role: {PIPELINE_ROLE}
        ...

        // stages
        stages: [
            {
               stageName: source,
               actions: {excluding}
            },
            {
               stageName: `Cross_Acct_Stage`,           
               actions: [crossAcctCrossRegionAction]
            }
        ]
   }

Finally, open terminal window and run npx aws-cdk deploy --all --app="npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts {path_to_stack}.ts" --require-approval never

Not sure if this helps but you can specify the region in the stack env prop and if you need a cross-region reference you will need to enable crossRegionReferences: true in the stack props. Also, make sure you bootstrap both regions. I have been able to use cross-account references but it requires a full ARN when you look up the resource. Not ideal..

Look into CDK Pipelines - they do all the work for you, including handling cross-env deployments.

Added code snippet. I was already doing all the suggestions above. I am not seeing the KMS error anymore. Now  its a CodePipeline permissions issue, which is easy to solve.

So it works now?

No. As stated, I am not getting the KMS error anymore. However, I am getting a CodePipeline > Role error. So we have made it one step further along the path. I do not have a working solution. i just made progress beyond the original KMS error.
